# WebSocket callback function multiple invocations

Tags: angularjs, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

I'm trying to create small web application which uses **WebSocket protocol** to exchange the data

Here is my angular service

```
define(function () {

    return function (module) {
        return module.service("socketService", function($q, $timeout) {

            var service = {},
                listener = $q.defer(),
                socket = {
                    client: null,
                    stomp: null
                };

            service.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30000;
            service.SOCKET_URL = "/service/booking";
            service.CHAT_TOPIC = "/service/booking/updates";
            service.CHAT_BROKER = "/service/booking";

            service.receive = function() {
                return listener.promise;
            };

            ...
            return service;
       });
   };
});
```

and also *controller* code

```
define(function () {
    return function (module) {
            socketService.receive().then(null, null, function(message) { 
                $scope.list.countDownTimer = 0;
                if(message.resourceId === parseInt($routeParams.resourceId)) {
                    $scope.list.bookings = [];
                }   
                ...     
            });
```

My problem is that *promise.then()* callback function is invoked many times and the amount of this invocations is not repeatable: it might be **2** times, **27** or even **110**.

One more thing that I should add is that I think that is somehow dependent with amount of users who tests and clicks on the application

Could anyone help?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Use events $on and $emit/$broadcast, promises only work with one return element at a time

Comment: @JesúsQuintana could you please explain how it related to the multiple *promise.then()* callback function invocations?

Comment: the .then callback being called multiple times doesn't make much sense,  unless your binding to it multiple times. my guess would be you controller is being invoked multiple times, and when it is no longer needed the callbacks aren't cleaned up, so they still trigger.